# Parse JSON column then add new column in the same dataframe with parsed value

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Case:

| column1 | column2 | json_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'} |

Desired output:

| column1 | column2 | json_column | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'} | 2 |

As seen here, json_column has been parsed and a new column 'B' has been created containing the value of key 'B' in the json_column.

Answer (score 2):

If the column is of string type, you could use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json):

```py
F.from_json('json_column', 'struct<A:string,B:string,C:string>')['B']
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('One', 'Two', "{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}")], ['column1', 'column2', 'json_column'])

df = df.withColumn('B', F.from_json('json_column', 'struct<A:string,B:string,C:string>')['B'])

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-------+-------+------------------------------+---+
# |column1|column2|json_column                   |B  |
# +-------+-------+------------------------------+---+
# |One    |Two    |{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}|2  |
# +-------+-------+------------------------------+---+
```